# How to login to WebService with REST protocol

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, httpwebrequest

I've got pdf with a description of API. I must login into their webservice. Webservice is based on REST protocol. To login into this webservice I have to call url like this:
http://api.webepartners.pl/wydawca/Authorize?login=test&password=pass

I have account and password. When I replace test and pass with my login and psw and past url into webbrowser it looks like is ok. No errors occur.
But I must do it programatically in C#.
In google I've found:
http://developer.yahoo.com/dotnet/howto-rest_cs.html

I try this code:

```
Uri address = new Uri(@"http://api.webepartners.pl/wydawca/Authorize");

            // Create the web request  
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;

            // Set type to POST  
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            // Create the data we want to send  
            //string appId = "YahooDemo";
            //string context = "Italian sculptors and painters of the renaissance"
            //                    + "favored the Virgin Mary for inspiration";
            //string query = "madonna";

            string userName = "mylogin";
            string passsword = "mypassword";

            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
            //data.Append("appid=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(appId));
            //data.Append("&context=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(context));
            //data.Append("&query=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(query));
            data.Append("login=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(userName));
            data.Append("&password=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(passsword));

            // Create a byte array of the data we want to send  
            byte[] byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data.ToString());

            // Set the content length in the request headers  
            request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;

            // Write data  
            using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
            }

            // Get response  
            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse) // error
            {
                // Get the response stream  
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            }
```

And I got error in the line  using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as ..

```
An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.
```

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending a POST request with username and password as part of the request body. But it seems that the web service expects a GET service where everything is in the URL of the request.

```
String uriStr = @"http://api.webepartners.pl/wydawca/Authorize?login="
    + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(userName) + "&password=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(passsword);
Uri address = new Uri(uriStr);
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;

// Get response 
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse) // error
{
    // Get the response stream  
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
}
```

.....
.....

```
GET http://api.webepartners.pl/wydawca/Authorize?from=2012-07-29%2013:47:05 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; encoding='utf-8'
Host: api.webepartners.pl
Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=7521F26EBCE8CE487C6860C5E98248B540E5591BD6AE7EC936ECE29B0912AC49C71837B98D7972ABA9C868F18A0C6FCD1EB38B22BE86DBCCCDF8D56D0440170FECF497FF00A1B5D7B268EF6DF27B2B9DB806291E517654A136EC5617A67182DB3E3ECF0D8ADA6F3927C2F955A92E20B7BF7AE6D7DAE2AED0B0D9A7BD406C2CF4


HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 29 Jul 2012 11:47:03 GMT
Content-Length: 1233

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</h2>
  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

That's it?

Comment: Ok Thanks it works. But Now I have to get next information:http://api.webepartners.pl/wydawca/Auctions?from=date. So I have to create second request ? What with authorization ?

Comment: I don't have more documentation. I create CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer(); and assign it to myHttpWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookies; I can see that I cookie is added, then I create myHttpWebRequest1 with new url and assing  myHttpWebRequest1.CookieContainer = cookies; but when I call HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse1 = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest1.GetResponse(); I get error: ... Forbidden. So authentication is wrong.

Comment: Based on the given information, it's difficult to tell where the problem is. Can you use a network monitor to trace the communication between the client and the server and post the transmitted requests and responses?

Comment: GET /wydawca/Authorize?login=testlog&password=F8-06-0F-23-67-26-FC-E1-45-99-D6-75-45-1D-B7-93 HTTP/1.1 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache 
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=0CC03337FCBB70847419BB71F3017EDC24BF6F746BF64ACC2CE8DD4DFDB9F2AC782472FF7D1035AFD411CDFCC804069FC3CAF5B68B885C45CCD693D47D9A8330EA3D6BEA6A6725ADD0887C5D125045953BF36561A50B9822C86AE794BE3BD21510365A470DD7A29914E990506FD56845CA5CB5C0845342240DE223FE22D7AFA5; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 29 Jul 2012 10:38:00 GMT
Content-Length: 0

Comment: Please append it to your question and show the second request/response as well.

Comment: CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
            HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://api.webepartners.pl/wydawca/Authorize?login=sdf&password=66-55");
            myHttpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
            myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
            myHttpWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;

            //Get Response
            HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader(myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream());

Comment: HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest1 = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(string.Format("http://api.webepartners.pl/wydawca/Authorize?from={0}",DateTime.Now));
            myHttpWebRequest.Credentials = myHttpWebRequest.Credentials;
            myHttpWebRequest1.Method = "GET";
            myHttpWebRequest1.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
            myHttpWebRequest1.CookieContainer = cookies;
       HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse1 = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest1.GetResponse();
  StreamReader myReader1 = new StreamReader(myHttpWebResponse1.GetResponseStream());

Comment: Don't you have the ability to edit your question? It's hardly readable as a comment. And I'm more interested in the network trace of the second request response (than in the code).

Comment: It wasn't supposed to be added to my answer but to the original question. Anyway, why is your second request an `Authorize` request again? Shouldn't it be first an `Authorize` request without cookie and then a different request with cookie?

Comment: Yes thank you very much. Second url should be http://api.webepartners.pl/wydawca/Auctions. My stupid error. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This url `http://api.webepartners.pl/wydawca/Authorize?login=test&password=pass` has a query string.  Since query string values are not used during a `POST`, maybe you should try a `GET` instead?  It would make sense that the HTTP verb you are using is incorrect with a `405` error.